# Wordpress updated posts on home page

Tags: wordpress, post, article, sticky

I've got a blog where I often have to update my articles. Now, I want the updated articles to be shown on the home page (as if they were created today). "Sticky" posts don't solve my problem and I didn't find any plugin that would do that for me. Changing the "created"-date isn't a solution as well because all posts have a url like myblog/YYYY/MM/DD/blogpost and it would change... so, any ideas? :)

Many thanks!

Comment: Mmmm... Is this really a programming question?

Comment: sure, I need to change my wordpress template somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind.

```
<?php global $query_string; ?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . 'order=DESC&orderby=modified'); ?>
```

does the job.